# Earth-based lightning on the Space Station channel

Tags: earth-observation, lightning

When watching the NASA channel (such as [on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wwMDvPCGeE0)) you see clouds and occasionally land forms. Why is it we never see electric storms on Earth ?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and explain what you mean with *electronic storms*? Maybe add links?

Comment: I think you mean [*electric* storms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderstorm)? An electronic storm would be something [quite different](https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/2MORQ8_Yc2WFgbr75X-GsAtIgmA=/0x0:5760x3840/1120x0/filters:focal(0x0:5760x3840):format(webp)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/5979723/GettyImages-454448721.jpg)

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify, please rollback if I've misinterpreted what you're asking!

Answer (score 5):

**We do!**

This [footage](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/av/science-environment-42188125/nasa-footage-shows-lightning-from-iss) shows a (sped up) view from the ISS passing over China, Korea and Japan with widespread lightning visible.
Another beautiful example is this annotated image of Saudi Arabia and Kuwait taken from the ISS, showing city a lightning storm between the city lights:

[image: Photograph from ISS showing Hafar Al Batin, Khafji, Kuwait city and a thunderstorm at night]
<sup>Image Credit: [NASA](https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/view.php?id=83387)</sup>

Since lightning strikes occur [40-50 times](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-mwbAsxpRr0C&pg=PA452&redir_esc=y&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false) *per second* over the surface of the Earth, if you watch the ISS livestream for long enough and the viewing conditions are good (ie. it's easier to see lightning on the night-side), you're *bound* to see some.

Comment: If the ISS flew in a low-inclination orbit, you'd see a lot more of these storms on the footage...